# Apple hardware, macOS vs. Windows 10 on Boot Camp for gaming

Tags: macos, windows-10, macbook-pro, boot-camp, gaming

Does installing Windows 10 on Apple hardware through Boot Camp result in significantly better performance on games than just using macOS? Particularly on the MacBook Pro with an AMD Radeon R9 M370X, and particularly with MOBAs, Overwatch, and No Man's Sky.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the games don't have native executables available, I'd say it's safe to assume that you'll have better performance under a real Windows compared to emulation.

However, the performance gains heavily depend on your actual hardware and the games being run.

Just don't expect any wonders, especially for *No Man's Sky*, a game many have issues with, even on the most powerful desktop systems.

While I can't say for sure, I'd expect maybe 5-10℅ more performance, considering how good hardware emulation became.